# Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate-invoke) - System.Net.HttpWebRequest

Tags: ios, xamarin, 64-bit, mvvmcross

After migration to Unified API (Xamarin) and upgrading MvvmCross to 3.5
(and retargeting PCL projects to profile 259 .net 4.5)
I get this error while trying to run the app on iPhone:

Attempting to JIT compile method '(wrapper delegate-invoke) :invoke_callvirt_void_HttpWebRequest_bool (System.Net.HttpWebRequest,bool)' while running with --aot-only. See http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/about/limitations for more information.

I disabled the linker. It doesn't help.
Anyone?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you've checked "Enable generic value type sharing" in the project's iOS Build options (Advanced page).

Comment: Hey Rolf, It is enabled. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you add "-v -v -v -v" to the additional mtouch arguments and then upload a full build log somewhere?

Comment: This is the link to the full build log: http://rumblephonebook.azurewebsites.net/buildlog.txt. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I used Microsoft.Http nuget which referenced System.Net.Http.dll. This dll is not the same as Mono System.Net.Http.dll.
I removed the nuget and used Mono dll instead (with ModernHttpClient).